# How to know if stored procedure is successful in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

How to know if stored procedure is successful in codeigniter

I am running my stored procedure like

```
$query= $this->db->query('call procedure(dsds)');
```

$query does not return 1
and affected_rows returns -1

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

If you are running a read query, `simple_query()` will return either **the object** or **null**.
If you are running a write query, `simple_query()` will return either **true** or **false** depending on success or failure.

You can also use `$this->db->simple_query()` which **only** returns a Boolean depending on success or failure.

Of course, I recommend using [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) over manual queries:

```
$this->db->set('field', 'value');
$this->db->insert('table_name'); // returns bool
```

Comment: I have a stored procedure in which there is an insert statement, how can I get to know if it is true and successful as I get the complete object in which I get affected_rows returned as -1.There is a blank num_rows